# How to set a black background color to an alert?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am currently developing an iOS application.
I have customized my alerts to match the colors of my app.
Here is the code:

```
func createPopUp(title: String, message: String, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style) -> UIAlertController {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: preferredStyle)
    
    alert.setTitlet(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17), color: UIColor.customOrange)
    alert.setMessage(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13), color: UIColor.customOrange)
    
    let subview = alert.view.subviews.first! as UIView
    let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
    alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // This is the important line
    alertContentView.tintColor = UIColor.customOrange
    alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    
    return alert
}
```

Only when I launch the app, I get this rendering:

[RenderingBlack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46aXT.png)

The background color is not black. However when I change the UIColor, for example :

```
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

The rendering is correct:

[RenderingGreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaje.png)

In spite of research on the net I can't find the solution.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello fiend please replace
`alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`
with `alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .black`

It will solve your problem.